# Excel VBA code throws run-time error 429 while sending Outlook email using Task Scheduler

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm using Excel VBA macro to send automated emails (Outlook 2013) which runs with Windows Task Scheduler (I'm using batch file to do that) at specified time every day. When I run my macro without Task Scheduler it executes normally (emails are sent), but when I use Task Scheduler for that I receive "run-time error 429", this only happens when the VBA macro tries to create Outlook object:

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'The error happens here
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .to = "email@email.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "subj"
    .Body = "body"
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

The above error only happens if the Outlook application is open on the computer.
Now what I don't understand is:

1. Why does the macro work normally WITHOUT Task Scheduler (Despite Outlook being open or not) and why doesn't it work there?
2. How to make the whole process execute using Task Scheduler and not to depend on Outlook app being open or closed? (i.e. I want the macro to run no matter which applications are open/closed).

Advice would be highly appreciated.

Edit: Here is the VBScript code I'm using to execute macro (in repsonse to  LS_ᴅᴇᴠ's question):

```
    Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Create an Excel instance
Dim myExcelWorker
Set myExcelWorker = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

' Disable Excel UI elements
myExcelWorker.DisplayAlerts = False
myExcelWorker.AskToUpdateLinks = False
myExcelWorker.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
myExcelWorker.FeatureInstall = msoFeatureInstallNone

' Tell Excel what the current working directory is 
' (otherwise it can't find the files)
Dim strSaveDefaultPath
Dim strPath
strSaveDefaultPath = myExcelWorker.DefaultFilePath
strPath = WshShell.CurrentDirectory
myExcelWorker.DefaultFilePath = strPath

' Open the Workbook specified on the command-line 
Dim oWorkBook
Dim strWorkerWB
strWorkerWB = strPath & "\____DailyReport.xlsm"

Set oWorkBook = myExcelWorker.Workbooks.Open(strWorkerWB)

' Build the macro name with the full path to the workbook
Dim strMacroName
strMacroName = "'" & strPath & "\____DailyReport.xlsm'" & "!Module1.____DailyRep"
on error resume next 
   ' Run the calculation macro
   myExcelWorker.Run strMacroName
   if err.number <> 0 Then
      ' Error occurred - just close it down.
   End If
   err.clear
on error goto 0 

'oWorkBook.Save 
'oWorkBook.Close <<--- we don't need these two because we close the WB in the VBA macro

myExcelWorker.DefaultFilePath = strSaveDefaultPath

' Clean up and shut down
Set oWorkBook = Nothing

' Don’t Quit() Excel if there are other Excel instances 
' running, Quit() will 
'shut those down also
if myExcelWorker.Workbooks.Count = 0 Then
   myExcelWorker.Quit
End If

Set myExcelWorker = Nothing
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Being this an Excel macro, what batch have you put in task scheduler?

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ I was using the VBScript described here: [Excel: Running Excel on Windows Task Scheduler](http://krgreenlee.blogspot.com/2006/04/excel-running-excel-on-windows-task.html) and my batch file looked like this: `start "" "D:\Documents\Macros\___\Run__Rep.vbs"`

Comment: So, another question... What does VBS contains?

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ I've edited the post (added the VBS code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the below:

1) Write in an excel file which saved as SendEmail.xlsm, your Sub:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub send_email()



Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .to = "email@email.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "subj"
    .Body = "body"
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

2) Open a notepad write this Code and save it as vbs (SendEmail.vbs)

```
Dim args, objExcel

Set args = WScript.Arguments
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Workbooks.Open args(0)
objExcel.Visible = True

objExcel.Run "send_email"

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(0)
objExcel.Quit
```

3) Open a notepad write this code and save as bat (SendEmail.bat),I have saved it on my desktop, you can save it everywhere you want.

```
cscript "D:\desktop\SendEmail.vbs" "D:\desktop\SendEmail.xlsm"
```

4) Create a task in the scheduler which calls the SendEmail.bat

Comment: many thanks! Your method worked out! I was using the method described here: Excel: [Running Excel on Windows Task Scheduler](http://krgreenlee.blogspot.com/2006/04/excel-running-excel-on-windows-task.html) but it wouldn't work out as I mentioned above. I only have one question left: in the script described on the website there's given way of not quitting Excel if there are other instances running, but with your script it still doesn't quit other instnaces of Excel, should I leave it as it is, or use that checking method?

Comment: do you want to quit all instances or only the instance of the script?

Comment: Only the instance of the script, meaning I want other instances to be left running (in case there are other instances).

Comment: What is `CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")` for?

Comment: Althrough your solution may work, you failed to identify OP issue and as well, you're not explaining why your answer is a solution to OP problem.

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ You have right, I just copy the sub that OP use and I forgot to erase CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell").i will be editing the answer.Thanks!!

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ  my answer for your second question is that I have explained the steps with details to make the whole thing work, and I have already answer to a new question that OP had.
I didn't only give to OP a code.
The OP problem was that does the macro work normally WITHOUT Task Scheduler and not with...with my answer OP can find the reason of the issue.

Comment: So, why doesn't the macro run with task scheduler?

Comment: I have already answer to this("with my answer OP can find the reason of the issue. ")

Answer (score 2):

The reason which was resulting in error was that I was trying to run the task "with highest privileges":[image]

This was apparently not feasible in my environment, so when I unchecked it both the VBScript I was using and VBScript suggested by @Nikolaos Polygenis execute normally.

Answer (score 1):

You should first check if Outlook is running and if so, attach to it and not creating a new session:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")    'Error if Outlook not running
On Error GoTo 0
If objOutlook Is Nothing Then  'Outlook not running so start it
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried to amend it your way, but unfortunately I'm getting the same error when trying to run it from Task Scheduler (otherwise it  works just fine, once again). The thing is that apparently when runing from Task Scheduler the code omitted 'GetObject ' line and threw an error at 'CreateObject' line.

Comment: You need to check the privileges for TS. Apparently they are not enough ...

Comment: You are totally correct. I was running the task with "highest privileges", when I unchecked it the script executed normally.